# How does google react to duplicate pages with text in a different language?

Tags: seo, google, search-engines, duplicate-content, multilingual

If there is a copy of a site in another language, but with same resource filenames, does Google not like the fact that the resources aren't in the same language as the page?

Comment: What exactly are these "resources" you're referring to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read [Google's help page on this](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=182192#1).

Comment: That was a good page to read.